# Knockout JS html binding returning weird code instead of html string

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
function tournamentViewModel(){
    var self= this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.districts = ko.observableArray([new district('Provo',1),new district('Salt Lake City',2),new district('St. George',3)]);
    self.district = ko.observableArray();
    self.regions = ko.observableArray([new region('Utah',1),new region('Idaho',2)]);
    self.region = ko.observableArray();
    self.location = ko.observable();
    self.date = ko.observable();
    self.startTime = ko.observable();
    self.image = ko.observable();
    self.flyer = ko.computed(function(){return '<h1>'+self.name+'</h1>'+self.image},self);
    self.clearImage = function(){
        self.image(''); 
    }
    self.tournamentID = ko.computed(function(){return 't_'+self.district+'_'+self.region+'_'+self.date}, self);
};
```

The above knockout.js view model seems to be fine except for when I want to bind something to the computed observable `flyer`. Instead, all I see is the following text:

```
<h1>function c(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!c.equalityComparer||!c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0]))c.I(),d=arguments[0],c.H();return this}a.U.La(c);return d}</h1>function c(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!c.equalityComparer||!c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0]))c.I(),d=arguments[0],c.H();return this}a.U.La(c);return d}
```

I don't know what's going on here. Below is the binding I'm applying it to. I've tried both html and text bindings.

```
<span data-bind="text: flyer"></span>
```

BTW the computed observable `tournamentID` works great and the syntax seems identical. I think the problem occurs when I use `self.name` in the computed observable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about it. What do you get? You get the function definition. Because you passed function to your `computed`. And you need to pass **values**. You should use:

```
self.flyer = ko.computed(function(){
    return '<h1>'+self.name()+'</h1>'+self.image();
});
```

since both `name` and `image` are observables (from JavaScript point of view: functions).

I'm not sure why `tournamentID` is working for you. It shouldn't.

BTW If you are using `var self = this;`, then you can omit the second argument of `computed`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I always miss something stupid. Also thanks for explaining your answer instead of just offering fixed code. It means a lot more to have the theory then just the code.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
<span data-bind="text: flyer()"></span>
```